# Webflux producer consumer problem (webClient)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Hi I have problem with WebFlux and backpressure:

```
    Flux.range(0, 100)
            .flatMap((Integer y) -> {
                return reallySlowApi(); 
            })
            .doOnEach((Signal<String> x1) -> {
                log("next-------" );
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .subscribe()
    ;
```

How I can limit calls like to one call per 5 seconds. Note: only reallySlowApi can be modified.

```
private Mono<String> reallySlowApi() {
    return webClient
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

Edit: I know about `delayElements` but it won't resolve issue if Api will get even slower. I need optimal way of working with `reallySlowApi`.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "optimal"? If you want your client to eventually succeed, then retry with backoff can be a good choice. If you want to protect the downstream you can look into ratelimiter and bulkhead from resilience4j: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started However, you'll need to provide some configuration like concurrency limit, or requests per second.

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Yes and No.Not that I'm happy but somehow it works. 
.flatMap((Integer y) -> { return reallySlowApi();}, 3) => flatMap(mapper, concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

One way is with delayElements()

```java
  public void run() {
    Flux.range(0, 100)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5)) // only emit every 5 seconds
        .flatMap(y -> reallySlowApi())
        .doOnNext(x1 -> System.out.println("next-------"))
        .blockLast(); // subscribe AND wait for the flux to complete
  }

  private Mono<String> reallySlowApi() {
    return Mono.just("next");
  }
```

You could also use Flux.interval() plus a take() to limit the number of iterations.

```java
   Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .take(100)
```

Note that the subscribeOn in your example doesn't do anything partcularly as the subscribe operation applies to the generation of the range 0-100 which is not blocking.

Comment: well what if the slow Api will slow down more (I will got backpressure and 429 Too many requests). Maybe is there a way to make "Mono.just("next");"  a singleton ? Maybe Semaphore..

Comment: I see so do you want to limit the number of concurrent requests? Do you want to limit the rate of requests even if the service responds quickly? Or just to produce backpressure in case the service responds slowly?

Comment: yes ... number of concurrent requests. I don't want to have time based limiter. more like 2 concurrent requests. I'm aware about parallel but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use retry mechanisam in ur webclient code**

```
.doOnError(error -> handleError(error.getMessage()))
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(ServiceConstants.FIVE))
            .retryWhen(
                    Retry.backoff(retryCount, Duration.ofSeconds(ServiceConstants.FIVE))
                            .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof TimeoutException)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put here solution that I found. WebFlux when mapping response we can pass **concurrency parameter** that solve this issue.

flatMap(mapper, **concurrency**)

```
.flatMap((Integer y) -> {
     return reallySlowApi(); 
 } , 3)
```